# Practical method to measure a data acquisition board's noise floor

Tags: noise, data-acquisition

Noise floor of a 16 bit system is usually within a few dB of 96 dB. And this is because

20*log10(2^16) = 96dB

But I guess this is the theoretical quantization noise floor. So if this was the only thing I would say for a 16-bit +/-10V DAQ the minimum voltage we can detect would be 20/2^16 = 305uV.

But in practice how can we measure the total noise floor? If I short the analog inputs of a 16-bit DAQ and sample it at a certain frequency and plot the data, would the rms of this data be the real noise floor?

(By noise floor I mean the DAQ's inherent noise which sets the minimum amount of voltage variation we can resolve)

Comment: Yes it would represent the noise in your system

Comment: For fun, provide 1milliVolt triangle wave (1vpp into 50Kohm and 51 ohm voltage divider). Then examine the output codes.

Comment: For yet more fun, connect a charged parallel RC that slowly discharges. This is a very low noise source, that slowly sweeps the input through many voltages. Examine the resulting readings for missing codes and differential non-linearity, as well as noise amplitude.

Comment: @Neil_UK The cap must be rather large, so the ADC's grab-some-more-charge delta_V_cap is << one ADC quanta, right? I like the idea.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf back in 1978, when a 25ks/s 12 bit ADC was something, and you had to build your own T/H for it, I used a 100uF // 10k for its first live measurement. OMG, why did codes xxxx xxxx xx11 never appear? Yup, output data lines running underneath the T/H amplifier.

Comment: Even Burr Brown's HiRel 10MHz 12 bit ADC had missing codes in 1978, so I ordered the commericial version, no problems. I figured crosstalk to Vref and Agnd inside the hybrid. But I tested with a triangle and DAC to compare